# how to match values in columns by group or within category (groupwise) with other column(having multiple values) in same dataframe in R

Tags: r, data.table

So, I have data table in R which looks like follows:

```
Claim failure Part code matchcode
23     F1     P1    A   B,A,C
23     F1     P1    D   B,A,C
23     F2     P2    D   B,A,C
23     F2     P2    E   B,A,C
45     F1     P4    X   Y,Z,X
45     F1     P4    Y   Y,Z,X
45     F1     P4    A   Y,Z,X
45     F1     P1    F   Y,Z,X
45     F1     P1    H   Y,Z,X
```

So the idea here is for every group (claim, failure and part) if 'any' of the code in 'code' matches with list of the codes in 'matchcode' column then than group should have Match column as True.

So expected output should be as following:

```
Claim failure Part Match 
23     F1     P1    TRUE   
23     F2     P2    FALSE  
45     F1     P4    TRUE
45     F1     P1    FALSE
```

The size of this data.table is huge so will be needing a optimized solution.
please help :)

Comment: If you want to vectorize/optimize regex operation, always use the stringi package. That will be by far faster than any alternative (at Ieast I know of). For your purposes I would just do `library(stringi) ; DT[, .(Match = any(stri_detect_fixed(matchcode, code))), by = .(Claim, failure, Part)]`. And I would also do some searching as vectorizing `grepl` is something that was discussed many times already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

... and a solution using `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
grepl_v <- Vectorize(grepl)
DT[, .(Match = any(grepl_v(code, matchcode))), by = .(Claim, failure, Part)]
#   Claim failure Part Match
#1:    23      F1   P1  TRUE
#2:    23      F2   P2 FALSE
#3:    45      F1   P4  TRUE
#4:    45      F1   P1 FALSE
```

**data**

```
DT <- fread("Claim failure Part code matchcode
23     F1     P1    A   B,A,C
23     F1     P1    D   B,A,C
23     F2     P2    D   B,A,C
23     F2     P2    E   B,A,C
45     F1     P4    X   Y,Z,X
45     F1     P4    Y   Y,Z,X
45     F1     P4    A   Y,Z,X
45     F1     P1    F   Y,Z,X
45     F1     P1    H   Y,Z,X")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `dplyr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Match = grepl(code, matchcode)) %>%
  group_by(Claim, failure, Part) %>%
  mutate(Match = any(Match)) %>%
  select(-code, -matchcode) %>%
  unique
## A tibble: 4 x 4
## Groups:   Claim, failure, Part [4]
#  Claim failure Part  Match
#  <int> <fct>   <fct> <lgl>
#1    23 F1      P1    TRUE 
#2    23 F2      P2    FALSE
#3    45 F1      P4    TRUE 
#4    45 F1      P1    FALSE
#Warning message:
#Grouping rowwise data frame strips rowwise nature
```

Don't worry about the warning, it simply tells you that after `grep`'ing rowwise, the pipe groups by certain variables and therefore the processing is no longer row by row.

**Data.**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "
Claim failure Part code matchcode
23     F1     P1    A   B,A,C
23     F1     P1    D   B,A,C
23     F2     P2    D   B,A,C
23     F2     P2    E   B,A,C
45     F1     P4    X   Y,Z,X
45     F1     P4    Y   Y,Z,X
45     F1     P4    A   Y,Z,X
45     F1     P1    F   Y,Z,X
45     F1     P1    H   Y,Z,X                  
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

`base` solution:

```
d$match <- apply(d, 1, function(x) { return(grepl(x[['code']], x['matchcode']))})

# Claim   failure Part code matchcode match
# 1    23      F1   P1    A     B,A,C     1
# 2    23      F1   P1    D     B,A,C     0
# 3    23      F2   P2    D     B,A,C     0
# 4    23      F2   P2    E     B,A,C     0
# 5    45      F1   P4    X     Y,Z,X     1
# 6    45      F1   P4    Y     Y,Z,X     1
# 7    45      F1   P4    A     Y,Z,X     0
# 8    45      F1   P1    F     Y,Z,X     0
# 9    45      F1   P1    H     Y,Z,X     0
```

Original version of this answer used `grep()`; thanks to [markus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8583393/markus) for suggesting `grepl()`